# equal height columns not working with resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

demo http://daysof.me/interview/

```
  $(".container").each(function(){
    boxes = $(this).find('.heightHack');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
      Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
      }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
  });
```

The code above work but it needed to be refreshed to see the result when I resized the windows.

I tried this :

```
function equalHeight(){
  $(".container").each(function(){
    boxes = $(this).find('.heightHack');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
      Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
      }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
  });
  setTimeout(equalHeight, 1000);
}

equalHeight();
```

but doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $(".container").each(function(){
    boxes = $(this).find('.heightHack');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
      Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
      }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
  });
});
```